# Can't acces login on new site

Tags: wp-admin

I created a new website that host Wordpress with Keliweb.
I opened the cPanel and installed Wordpress in my domain. I have received all the information to enter the login page, but when I try to open it I get this error:

> IIS 8.5 Detailed Error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

On the installer (Softaculous) it says that Wordpress is installed and running, but I can't accces the login page.
Here are the detail of the error:

Detailed Error Information:

Module     IIS Web Core

Notification       MapRequestHandler

Handler    StaticFile

Error Code     0x80070002

Requested URL      http://www.test.it:80/sapp-wp-signon.php?pass=i8mrvbbvm5zwuezihhoy6p0xrc4wwd2h
(I put test.it for privacy reason)

Physical Path      D:\inetpub\wwwroot\sapp-wp-signon.php

Logon Method       Anonymous

Logon User     Anonymous

Request Tracing Directory      D:\LogFiles\FailedReqLogFiles

Can somebody help me?

Comment: For starters, you've installed WordPress on Windows hosting instead of Linux. Are you able to switch to Linux instead? You can use Windows I think but Linux won't require you to make changes to how rewrites are handled for WordPress.

Comment: WordPress on IIS is a massive pain in the ass and if you can, avoid it.